# Adding more key value pairs to interface when using a string index in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the code below I get the following error: Property 'latlng' of type 'LatLng[]' is not assignable to string index type 'string[]'.ts(2411). Am I not allowed to have a string index in Typescript? How can I fix this?

```
interface LatLng {
  lat: number;
  long: number;
}
export interface Country {
  [countryName: string]: Capital[];
  latlng: LatLng[];
}

type Capital = string;
```

This is how I am setting the array from the API

```
 const randomCountries = randomCountriesFull.map((country) => {
        return {
          [country.name.common]: country.capital,
          latlng: country.latlng,
        };
      });
```

Comment: would be helpful if you can add some context as to what you're trying to achieve, its not so clear from this

Comment: because rn there's a conflict because you're creating Country as string -> Capital[] and also saying latlng -> LatLng[] . You can see if you change from string to string&{latlng:never} it will accept but may be cleaner approaches

Comment: What does your `country.latlng` look like? It should be something like this to work correctly `[{ lat: 12.345, lng: 12: 12345 }, ...]`

Comment: This is not directly possible; see the answer to the linked question for the various options available.